# figures in an appendix, list of figures in frontmatter, to be compiled separately

Tags: table-of-contents

How would I best approach the problem of having an appendix for images, but the corresponding LoF as part of the frontmatter, in files compiled separately? I saw that `combine` has some facilities for that, what would be other solutions?

In the worst case I guess I could fit both in one tex file with pagenumbers and possibly some other things set manually, then split up the pdf generated from it and place the resulting halves at their appropriate places using `pdfpages`.

Some other suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Well, all figures in the appendix? Do you place them manually there? What's the problem in using `\listoffigures` in the frontmatter? `\listoffigure` can be placed basically anywhere in the document body

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, this is for an edited volume, and I'm afraid I won't be able to compile all the chapters in one go due to conflicting packages/package options used by the different authors. The images  are indeed manually placed into an appendix, and are probably going to be printed on high-gloss-paper.

Comment: The edited volume is an important information missing in the question ;-) And what do you mean by placing it there? Do you literally glue them on paper?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer "Manually placed", well they are regularly placed into their appendix using `figure`s and `\includegraphics`. The "manually" referred to their association with the respective chapters via numbering, captions and sectioning of the appendix having to correspond to the chapters of the volume. Thinking about which there might also be a way to let latex handle that for you, but that part of the work is already mostly done.

Comment: @mukli: Yes, but it remains unclear to us, what you've actually done -- which in turn commands the strategy, somehow

Comment: @ChristianHupfer And of course, even if I might be forced to work with \includepdf and a manual setting of page numbers etc. for the individual chapters, I will still be able to keep the LoF in the frontmatter and the images in the appendix of the containing document, so in a way your first comment already contained the obvious answer to the problem which I just didn't see.

Comment: Use package `endfloat`, it does just that. It places all figures and tables if you want at the end of document.

Comment: not in a position to test, but i'd approach this in the following way.  (1) make a copy of the `.lof` file after the appendix is complete (with the correct page numbers); (2) rename it to something compatible with the name of the "main" book (but *not* `xxx.lof`); (3) define a command that will do the formatting that `\listoffigures` does but doesn't open a new `.lof` file; (4) `\input` the saved file with the figure data in the appropriate place.  (please expand your question with the information about why you need to do this separately.)

Comment: If you use `\includepdf`, why would you set the page numbers manually? Just create the chapters without page numbers and then add them when they are included.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, something like that I was thinking of. Although I might not really need to do it in the end, as I could keep the LoF and the appendix with the images in the main file. Still it will be a good exercise and teach me a lot about LoFs and friends.

Comment: @cfr Sometimes one just needs to be told the obvious. Although it's not only the page numbers, it's the whole headers and footers, but of course they can be dealt with in the main file.